# Div 1 line text = bottom, Div more than 1 line = top

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS Template: http://jsfiddle.net/qubordgg/1/

This is what I want to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/mLu6ppLe/

As you can see there I try to make a CSS-based solution that will put the

```css
.text
```

1 line down when there is only 1 line of text.
But if there is more than 1 line, it will start on the top.

Is it possible in a CSS and HTML solution only? I don't want to use JS for that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`position:absolute` inside a `position:relative` is what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/qubordgg/2/

You need to say to the right div: position yourself at the bottom of the container element. The container has to have `position:relative` for this to work.

Wrap your right part inside a div and then:

```css
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 60px;
}
.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Almost what I want. Do you know how I can get this working: http://jsfiddle.net/qubordgg/3/? Obviosly, the 3 lines need to start at the same point like the 2 lines container above.

Comment: for that you need javascript, because you are aligning to bottom, but now, if there are 4 lines, you need it to align it tot top. Either javascript, or apply different rules to 4 lines elements

Comment: When applying different rules, I need to apply a rule for every count of lines?